# Issues to load a dictionary in a tree structure and unload it - C programming

Tags: c, pointers, dictionary, tree, cs50

I'm still trying to debug my load function which one is supposed to load a dictionary file. I rewrite my code again and again but with no result... I know we need to have specific question, but now I just have so many questions. So, I'll go with what I think is the source of my error. I think I don't initialize my two pointers correctly, by initialized, I mean allocate the memory and define them a specific type of value.

There, how I define and initialize the structure of my nodes and pointers :

```
#include "dictionary.h"
#define NB_NODES 27

// define global structure and pointers
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node* children[NB_NODES];
} node;

// initialize pointers and variables
node* root = NULL;
node* current = NULL;
int word_counter = 0;
```

Now, there is my implementation of LOAD :

```
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
// open dictionary file
FILE* inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");

if (inptr == NULL)
{
    printf("fail to open dictionary\n");
    return false;
}

// initialize tools
root = malloc(sizeof(node));
word_counter = 0;
int index = 0;
current = root;

// looks for word until end reached
for (int c = fgetc(inptr); c != EOF; c = fgetc(inptr))
{
    // looking words one by one
    if (c != '\n')
    {
        if (c == '\'')
        {
            index = 26;

            if (current->children[index] == NULL)
            {
                current->children[index] = calloc(1, sizeof(node));

                // test
                if (current->children[index] == NULL)
                {
                    printf("error with apostrophe");
                    return 1;
                }

            }
        }

        else
        {
            index = c - 'a';

            if (current->children[index] == NULL)
            {
                current->children[index] = calloc(1, sizeof(node));

                // test
                if (current->children[index] == NULL)
                {
                    printf("error with characters");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // update current pointer to the next node
        current = current->children[index];
    }

    else if (c == '\n')
    {
        // new word found
        if (current->is_word == false)
        {
            current->is_word = true;
            word_counter++;
            current = root;
        }

        // duplicate word
        else
        {
            current = root;
        }
    }

    // character not found
    else 
    {
        printf("character not found");
        return 2;
    }
}

fclose(inptr);
return true;
}
```

So in my headers statements, I declare my pointers equal to NULL, and let them accessible by all sub functions (global variable). After, in the top of LOAD, I allocate memory size of a node, to my pointer root. I have tried many ways to code this but the one shared appear me to be the most logical.

I also have doubt about the way I reinitialize the root pointers after a complete word is found. May be in doing that, the way I do, I "lost" the track of the word just found?

Help would really be appreciated on this case to continue debugging because this is not my only issue!

Here the main error I get when I tried to run speller, main function calling load :

```
jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/pset5): ./speller                  ~cs50/pset5/dictionaries/small/austinpowers.txt
Could not open /home/cs50/pset5/dictionaries/small/austinpowers.txt.
*** Error in `./speller': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x094302d8 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/pset5):
```

I also launched speller in gdb and got this error :

```
jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/pset5): gdb ./speller
Reading symbols from ./speller...done.
(gdb) run ~cs50/pset5/dictionaries/small/austinpowers.txt
Starting program: /home/jharvard/Dropbox/pset5/speller     ~cs50/pset5/dictionaries/small/austinpowers.txt
Could not open /home/cs50/pset5/dictionaries/small/austinpowers.txt.
*** Error in `/home/jharvard/Dropbox/pset5/speller': double free or     corruption (!prev): 0x0804c2d8 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb7fdd428 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb)
```

Curiously when I go forward step by step in gdb, I can go through my load loop without receiving failures...

There is my code of UNLOAD (REVISED) :

```
bool unload(void)
{
// recursive_free prototype
void recursive_free (node* node_to_free);

    recursive_free(root);

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else return false;
}


void recursive_free (node* node_to_free)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_NODES; i++)
    {
        // node created to assign memory to free if children found
        node* temp;

        // if children found
        if (node_to_free->children[i])
        {
            temp = node_to_free;
            node_to_free = node_to_free->children[i];
            free(temp);
            recursive_free(node_to_free);
        }

        else free(node_to_free);
    }
}
```

If some more stuffs is needed to help me, just ask, and I will add. Thanks for your times guys.

Comment: While freeing in function , you use recursion as well as loop . Why ? That may be cause of double `free` .

Comment: Because each node has 27 children. So at each node I must iterate to see all of them. @ameyCU

Comment: Is this a CS50 pset?

Comment: I copied your load as I find it a good dictionary loader. A few notes: 1) all characters in the input must be lowercase - I suggest to use `index= tolower(c) - 'a'`. 2) the part `character not found` will never be reached. 3) each word must be on a separate line - you can use `isspace(c)` to ignore all space characters. 4) `current` does not need to be global.

Comment: ...and the biggest bug of all: `root = malloc(sizeof(node));`, which must also be a `calloc` to get zeroed memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load function looks OK. In your unload function you must first descend all nodes, then free the bottom node, then go one level up etcetera:

```
void recursive_free (node* node_to_free)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_NODES; i++)
    {
        // if children found
        if (node_to_free->children[i])
        {
            recursive_free(node_to_free->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(node_to_free);
}
```

Comment: Ok ok, but in doing this way, am I suppose to add a function to go on levels up once the bottom is reached?@ PaulOgilvie

Comment: The function as presented is what you need. It recursively deletes the nodes. Didn't you see????

Comment: Honestly I see that function is going to the bottom and then deletes the last node but after I only see that function will step to the next node of the root and repeat...@PaulOgilvie

Comment: Nope. It will recursively go to the bottom, deletes all the children of the bottom node, deletes that node, returns (and so goes one level up!), deletes all remain children in recusive calls, deletes the node, returns (goes one level up!) etcetera. Try to envision the call stack in your mind, or use a debugger to step you through the behavior.